# How many Dalit Muslims were there in India in 1900 AD?

Tags: india, religion

The Wikipedia entry about [Dalits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalit) has no section regarding how many Dalits are adherents of Islam  (though it has extensive information regarding Hindu, Buddhist and Sikh Dalits). It has a table that shows:

[image]

My question is: How many Dalit Muslims were there in India in 1900 AD? (or in the early 20th century if exact data is not available)

Comment: In the last paragraph, do you mean the "early 19th century" or the early 20th Century (i.e. ~1901-1920)?

Comment: @SteveBird Question updated. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Were there any? I thought Dalit was a Hindu caste and as such would no longer be applied to converts to Islam or Christianity. Buddhism and Sikhism are sometimes treated as branches of Hinduism.